# How to give role when user send message

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to give a role when user send message any text channel. But I am making mistake somewhere. What should we do?

I tried .on message listener but I am getting error.

```
bot.on("message", msg => {
  var sender = msg.author;
  var message= msg.content.toLowerCase();

  if (sender.id === "584268800715915264") {
    return;
  }
  var role = sender.guild.roles.find(val => val.name === "new role8");
  if (message) {
    sender.addRole(role);
  }
});
```

I get this error message at console.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. I just change code to this

```
if (message) {
    msg.member.addRole("584619478164307979");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all of that, just set code inside the event to

```js
msg.author.addRole(/*The role thingy goes here*/)
```